# Connecting your designed IOS app to your Dynamics 365 CRM solution through swift?

Tags: ios, swift, dynamics-crm

I'm creating a new ios application that enables the user to login to his/her account through CRM to be able to view specific data through the app for easier user such as charts or posts, instead of having to login to the whole solution on pc etc... 
But I do not know where to start, please help !

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Dynamics 365 Online? If, yes take a look at PowerApps. You can create A canvas App via Drag & drop and Little Bit of Code.

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/getting-started

If you really want to build Everything by yourself, just use the Dynamics CRM WebApi. There are a lot of good Tutorials out there

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/query-data-web-api#basic-query-example